# How to use a custom style with sort-imports extention for VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, package.json, vscode-extensions

I recently installed the VS Code extension [`sort-imports`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amatiasq.sort-imports&ssr=false#overview), and have attempted to use a custom style called [`import-sort-style-module-alias`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-sort-style-module-alias).

I believe I have followed the (bare-bones) instructions for proper installation (`npm i import-sort-style-module-alias`), and included the `"importSort"` property in my package.json file (see below).  However, the sort-imports extension does not seem to be recognizing the custom style.  (The default styles work fine.) I have restarted VS Code, and rebuilt my project.

What step am I missing to get `sort-imports` to recognize the custom style I am attempting to use? I have not found any stackoverflow questions that cover this - and Google searching did not help either.

package.json (pared-down):

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies":{
    ...
  },
  "importSort": {
    ".js, .jsx, .es6, .es": {
      "parser": "babylon",
      "style": "module-alias",
      "options": {
        "alias": [
          "@aliasA",
          "@aliasB"
        ]
      }
    },
    ".ts, .tsx": {
      "parser": "typescript",
      "style": "module-alias",
      "options": {
        "alias": [
          "@aliasA",
          "@aliasB"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my `tsconfig.json` file (pared down):

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "paths": {
      "@aliasA/*": ["projects/appA/src/*"],
      "@aliasB/*": ["projects/appB/src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Update:**
I learned there is a `Sort-Imports` console, which was showing an error:

`parser.parseImports is not a function`

How can I address this error being thrown in `Sort-Imports` console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fix is mentioned in the extension [page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amatiasq.sort-imports&ssr=false#overview):

> Troubleshooting
>   `parser.parseImports` is not a function
>
> This happens when using Typescript parser (import-sort#72).
>   The solution is to install it manually:
>
> `npm i -D import-sort-parser-typescript`